# Do I need a motorcycle licence to ride a motorcycle in Bolivia?

Tags: driving-licenses, bolivia, motorcycles

I have a [type B European drivers licence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_driving_licence) with which I'm allowed to drive a car in my home country (i.e. not a motorcycle). Am I allowed to buy/rent a motorcycle in Bolivia and drive it? 
If not, should I get a motor licence here, or is it also possible to get one (as a tourist) in Bolivia?

Comment: For those who maybe don't know the European license codes - are you allowed to ride a motorbike in your home country on that license?

Comment: No, not allowed. I hoped the link to the wiki was clear enough. Apparently not, so I've edited my question to explain the situation better.

Comment: How much experience of riding a motorbike do you have, and why don't you have a license to drive on in your home country?

Comment: No experience (only drove a scooter several times), and it's too expensive.

Comment: You have no road experience in Bolivia which has a traffic fatality rate per vehicle which is 20-30 times higher than in the EU, you have no experience with a motorbike which increases the likelihood to be killed or maimed by the factor 7 *if you are experienced*, but you "have thought of that and understand the risks involved". Rrrrright. To optimize your fun do not forget to rent a Kawasaki Ninja with 1200 cc. And for the ultimate adrenaline rush use your T-Shirt and Jeans which is a) cool and b) gives you an incentive to prevent falling because you know it will rip your skin off.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I appreciate your concern, but I don't see how this is relevant to my question. I didn't mention anything like "how safe is it to ride a motorcycle in Bolivia", so please stay on topic. You've answered the question to the extent of your knowledge on this topic, thank you for that. If I have concerns about the road safety in Bolivia I will ask a separate question and this will give you an opportunity to show your knowledge on the safety there, but it's not the time yet.

Comment: @BartArondson: No problem, go ahead, I have a quiet conscience now.

Comment: No, you may only drive what you are licensed to drive, and as you say yourself, this does not include a motorcycle. My brother undertook a similar endeavour to what you planned - renting a motorcycle in Vietnam with no previous experience riding one. He came off it on a mountain road and was very lucky to not go over the side OR under the oncoming truck that had spooked him off it in the first place. He took off all the skin down one side of his body though. If you want to ride a motorbike, learnt to ride a motorbike. No matter which country your in, the law typically requires this much of you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get an [international driving permit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit) from your home country. It is no problem at all to rent motorcycles and cars with that *if you have the requirement in your original driving license*. While the convention says that you should have your original driving license available I never have done that (could be lost) and I have been never asked for that.

So strictly speaking legally *no, it is not possible to drive a motorcycle with only an automobile license*. If it is tolerated (some countries do not enforce street traffic very strictly) I do not know, perhaps someone from Bolivia or traveling to it could answer that.

As I have a motorcycle license myself I am sorry to say this, but driving a motorcycle in a third-world country if you have no road experience is asking to get killed. You need to drive carefully even here because you have to get the "sense" how people react because you have no protection against collisions and stupid drivers (the leather gear and helmet only protects against falling down (sometimes deliberately to save your life)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see you mention renting cars, but I'm mostly interested in riding a motorcycle. From the link you provided it seems I will not be allowed to do so (type B does not allow using a motorcycle if I understand correctly). Could you maybe augment your answer regarding motorcycle riding?

Comment: OK, now I'm a bit confused. `No problem at all to rent motorcycles and cars with that` conflicts with `So strictly speaking legally no, it is not possible to drive a motorcycle`. Which of the two is it? Thank you for the remark on safety, I've thought of that and understand the risks involved.

Comment: Edited answer to answer the correct question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check to see if your international license permits you to drive a motorcycle. Bolivia, like most other countries, expects you to have a special license to ride a motorcycle.

Here in Bolivia there are check points checking to see if you have the correct paperwork. Being a foreigner they will probably give you more trouble than if you were a native.

To get a Bolivian drivers' license you need to be a resident.

You need a local medical checkup and you have to go to drivers school. You will also need several certificates from several different police stations.

Here is a link for reference:
 http://www.segip.gob.bo/web/index.php/requisitos-para-obtener-la-licencia-para-conducir